# How do I use Source.asSubscriber to wrap reactive listener?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

How do I use `Source.asSubscriber` to wrap reactive listener ? I fail to understand its benefit.

I'm trying to create `Source[T]` for [asynchttpclient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) WebSocket. Here is my code:

```
def createWsObservable(url: String, onStartAction: Option[WebSocket ⇒ Unit]): Source[WsMessage, KillSwitch] =
  Source.asSubscriber[WsMessage].mapMaterializedValue { subs: Subscriber[WsMessage] ⇒
    val listener: WebSocketListener = new WebSocketListener() {
      override def onOpen(ws: WebSocket): Unit =
        subs.onNext(WsOpen(ws))

      override def onClose(ws: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String): Unit =
        subs.onComplete()

      override def onBinaryFrame(payload: Array[Byte], finalFragment: Boolean, rsv: Int): Unit =
        // Doing bunch of stuff here
        subs.onNext(...)

      override def onTextFrame(payload: String, finalFragment: Boolean, rsv: Int): Unit =
        // Doing bunch of stuff here
        subs.onNext(...)

      override def onError(t: Throwable): Unit =
        subs.onError(t)

      override def onPongFrame(payload: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
        super.onPingFrame(payload)
      }
    }

    val websocket =
      asyncHttpClient
        .prepareGet(url)
        .execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().addWebSocketListener(listener).build).get

    new KillSwitch {
      override def shutdown(): Unit = websocket.sendCloseFrame()
      override def abort(ex: Throwable): Unit = websocket.sendCloseFrame()
    }
  }
```

On first event I get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: spec violation: onNext was signaled from upstream without demand
    at akka.stream.impl.VirtualProcessor.rec$5(StreamLayout.scala:239)
    at akka.stream.impl.VirtualProcessor.onNext(StreamLayout.scala:243)
    at ingestion.NettyClientWrapper$$anon$2.onOpen(NettyClientWrapper.scala:55)
```

Perhaps `Source.asSubscriber` is bad choice for me ? What should I do to wrap reactivestreams Subscriber into akka's Source ?

Comment: ```
      override def onPongFrame(payload: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
        super.onPingFrame(payload)
      }```

looks like a typo, maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Source.actorRef` with `KillSwitch`

```
def createWsObservable(url: String, onStartAction: WebSocket ⇒ Option[KillSwitch] = _ ⇒ None, bufferSize: Int = 32): Source[WsMessage, KillSwitch] = {
  val actorSource = Source.actorRef[WsMessage](bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.fail)
  actorSource.mapMaterializedValue { actor ⇒
    val listener: WebSocketListener = new WebSocketListener() {

      override def onOpen(ws: WebSocket): Unit =
        actor ! ...

      override def onClose(ws: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String): Unit =
        actor ! akka.actor.Status.Success(code)

      override def onBinaryFrame(payload: Array[Byte], finalFragment: Boolean, rsv: Int): Unit =
        actor ! ...

      override def onTextFrame(payload: String, finalFragment: Boolean, rsv: Int): Unit =
        actor ! ...

      override def onError(t: Throwable): Unit =
        actor ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(t)
    }

    val websocket =
      asyncHttpClient
        .prepareGet(url)
        .execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().addWebSocketListener(listener).build).get

    // Use Pong reply as indication that we've connected to the server
    val p = Promise[Void]()
    websocket.sendPingFrame().addListener(p)
    val onStartKillSwitchFut = p.future.map(_ ⇒ onStartAction(websocket))

    new KillSwitch {
      override def shutdown(): Unit = {
        onStartKillSwitchFut.map(_.foreach(_.shutdown()))
        websocket.sendCloseFrame()
      }

      override def abort(ex: Throwable): Unit = {
        onStartKillSwitchFut.map(_.foreach(_.abort(ex)))
        websocket.sendCloseFrame()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Publisher` that you want to expose as a `Source`, you can use `Source.fromPublisher`.

In your case, the first question is how to obtain a `Publisher` from AHC. I don't know AHC, but from what I'm reading it's unclear if you can simultaneously have both Reactive Streams support (which requires you to pass a `StreamedAsyncHandler` to the `execute` method) and WebSocket support (which requires a `WebSocketUpgradeHandler` instead). I hope it's possible to compose them together.